# How do I make my Carousel view clickable?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been trying for some time now to make my carousel view clickable and use it to navigate to other pages/shells.
Here is my code:

```
 <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" HeightRequest="280" PeekAreaInsets="100">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:NewGames">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame HeightRequest="300" 
                                 WidthRequest="180" 
                                 BackgroundColor="white" 
                                 Padding="0" 
                                 CornerRadius="10"
                                 HasShadow="True" 
                                 Margin="15"
                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Grid>
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="DimGray">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFill">
                                    </Image>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Margin="-5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding GameTitle}" 
                                         TextColor="PaleGoldenrod"
                                         FontSize="18" 
                                         FontAttributes="Bold"
                                         Margin="15"
                                         VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

I looked at the xamarin documantation under the carousel view tab but I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: if you want the whole thing to be "clickable", add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `StackLayout` or `Frame`

Comment: How do I add a tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `Frame` as Jason suggested like below.

**Xaml:**

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" HeightRequest="280" PeekAreaInsets="100">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:NewGames">
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Frame HeightRequest="300" 
                                 WidthRequest="180" 
                                 BackgroundColor="white" 
                                 Padding="0" 
                                 CornerRadius="10"
                                 HasShadow="True" 
                                 Margin="15"
                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                
                              <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                     <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                         Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped">
                                     </TapGestureRecognizer>
                             </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                                <Grid>
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="DimGray">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFill">
                                    </Image>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Margin="-5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding GameTitle}" 
                                         TextColor="PaleGoldenrod"
                                         FontSize="18" 
                                         FontAttributes="Bold"
                                         Margin="15"
                                         VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //navigate to other pages/shells
     await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());
}
```

Comment: What if I have a list of things in my carousel view and I want the user to navigate to a different page based on the item he clicked, how do I code that?

Comment: @sunboy The `CarouselView` is a view for presenting data in a `scrollable` layout, where users can swipe to move through a collection of items.  If you want to navigate to other pages, you can see my update.

Comment: it's been solved thanks for asking